# Metadata for field visibility

Tags: custom-field, metadata, visibility

I am new to salesforce, so my question may seem basic.

Whenever we create a field, we set the visibility/read-only for various profiles.

How do i get that info in metadata? I created a field on Case object, then used workbench to retrieve the Case object. Following is all the info i see in Case.object (i have removed other info for convenience, just kept info for the new field here)

```
<fields>
        <fullName>Escalated_To__c</fullName>
        <deleteConstraint>SetNull</deleteConstraint>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Escalated To</label>
        <referenceTo>User</referenceTo>
        <relationshipName>CasesQCk0</relationshipName>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Lookup</type>
    </fields>
```

I didn't see anything else about this field in Case.object metadata file. How do i get the info i put in about profile visibility while creating the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored in the **profile** metadata. It will show up in the profile like:

```
<objectPermissions>
        <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
        <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
        <object>MyCustomObject__c</object>
        <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
</objectPermissions>
```

This way, you grant this permission to every user with the profile to Create, Delete, Edit and Read, etc.